# Left Join base on CASE

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make a Left Join in MySQL. The join is base on a condition. For example, if the value is `328`, `use Left Join <table A>` **ELSE** use `Left Join <table B>`

Below are the queries:

```
SELECT * FROM applications app
CASE 
WHEN 
    app.application_type = 328 
THEN
    LEFT JOIN application_individu ai 
    ON app.id = ai.application_id 
ELSE
    LEFT JOIN application_org ao 
    ON app.id = ao.application_id 
END
WHERE app.id=11
```

I received an error msg on `phpmyadmin`

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 
'(CASE WHEN app.application_type = 328 THEN
 LEFT JOIN application_individu a' at line 5
```

<del>1. Can we use `CASE` for join?</del>

<del>2. If possible, how to do it the correct way?</del>

> **Update Data**

Below are the sample data.

**applications**

```
id  application_type  app_reference  applicant_type  status created_date
1   330               ZAK00001       328             1      2019-01-16 16:45:14
2   330               ZAK00002       328             1      2019-01-17 12:31:14
3   330               ZAK00003       329             2      2019-01-17 14:31:40
```

**application_individu**

```
id   application_id  name  age  gender  contactNo  ic
1    1               Ali   30   Male    1234       12345678
2    2               Chan  45   Male    1234       54321
```

**application_org**

```
id   application_id  companyName  companyRegNo  picName  picContactNo  companyEmail
1    3               My StartUp   x-123Y        Raja     01035562      example@mystartup.com
```

**parameters**

```
id  parameterValue  detail
1   328             Personal              
2   329             Company
3   1               Complete
4   2               Pending
```

This is my updated query without the use of `CASE`.

```
SELECT * FROM applications app
LEFT JOIN application_individu ai ON app.id=ai.application_id
LEFT JOIN application_org ao ON app.id=ao.application_id
LEFT JOIN parameters param ON app.applicant_type=param.main_id
LEFT JOIN parameters param2 ON app.status=param2.main_id
LEFT JOIN parameters param3 ON app.applicant_type=param3.main_id
LEFT JOIN parameters param4 ON app.status=param4.main_id
```

Is there way to check if the application is `Personal` or `Company` so that I will not repeat the parameters on the join.

Comment: share sample data and output

Comment: you need to use dynamic sql for such cases

Comment: 1 - no you cannot use case try searching for mysql condtional join.

Comment: A SQL query results in a table with before-known columns. Do `application_individu` and `application_org` have exactly the same columns? (If so, then why two tables instead of one with an individu/org flag?) Or are you only interested in certain columns that exist in both tables? Please show sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Will update my question later. Currently away from my pc

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I updated my question with the sample data

Comment: Okay. That has changed your request somewhat. Next time you should add sample data immediately, including the expected result (which is still missing from your request here). You would show the expected result in the same format as the source tables. Well, a query result *is* itself a table after all, which is why we can select from a query result.

Answer (score 2):

you could use union

```
   SELECT app.* FROM applications app    
        LEFT JOIN application_individu ai 
        ON app.id = ai.application_id
    where app.application_type = 328 
union 
SELECT app.* FROM applications app    
       LEFT JOIN application_org ao 
       ON app.id = ao.application_id 
    where app.application_type != 328
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put the logic in the `ON` clause.  *And* remember to use `COALESCE()` in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT a.*,
       COALESCE(ai.name, ao.name) as name
FROM applications a LEFT JOIN
     application_individu ai
     ON a.id = ai.application_id AND
        a.application_type = 328 LEFT JOIN     
    application_org ao 
    ON a.id = ao.application_id  AND
       a.id = 11;
```

Do not use `SELECT *` when you are referencing multiple tables.  At the very least, you will have naming conflicts when columns have the same name in different tables -- which is very likely to occur in this case.

Answer (score 1):

To join tables conditionally, simply means to outer join them in SQL. So you have either one information or the other in your result row. You'll end up with a query like the one you've added to your request.

A combined parameter table doesn't make sense in my opinion. Have a status table and an applicant_type table instead, so you can apply proper foreign keys and know which is which.

The query would look something like this:

```
SELECT
  app.app_reference, created_date, s.status_text, apt.type_text,
  ai.name, ai.age,
  ao.companyName, ao.companyRegNo
FROM applications app
INNER JOIN status s ON s.id = app.status_id
INNER JOIN applicant_type apt on apt.id = app.applicant_type_id
LEFT JOIN application_individu ai ON app.id = ai.application_id
LEFT JOIN application_org ao ON app.id = ao.application_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - using left join with applying condition in ON cluase

```
    SELECT * FROM applications app
    left join application_individu ai ON app.id = ai.application_id
    and app.application_type = 328 
    LEFT JOIN application_org ao ON app.id = ao.application_id 
    WHERE app.id=11
```